# How can I cast an object to DbSet<MyClass> where I have the type of MyClass?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I want to do this:

`var castedDbSet = (DbSet<Type.GetType("MyClassType")>)theDbSet;`

where `theDbSet` is of type object in the code but the compiler knows it is of type `DbSet<MyClass>`.

How can I achieve this? The above code obviously does not work.

Comment: `(DbSet<MyClassType>)theDbSet`?

Comment: You can't **cast** to a type only known at runtime. Casting is a compile-time construct. (With a run-time check that it was valid.) The compiler can't know what the result of `Type.GetType(className)` is. What exactly would `var` mean in your example?

Comment: Show a more complete use case, maybe there's a better way to do what you're trying to accomplish. Like, say, just using the non-generic `DbSet` or `IQueryable<object>` and casting later. Or make the class name a generic parameter of the method instead of using reflection.

Comment: I guess what you have done and what you are now facing! Let me know if I am right, so I'll give you the solution. I think you have written a method with a parameter of type DbSet instead of DbSet<T> therefore you've lost many functionalities. Now you are wanting to convert back to the Generic one. I that Right?

Comment: You: _where `theDbSet` is of type object in the code but the compiler knows it is of type `DbSet<MyClass>`._ If the compile-time type (i.e. the declared type where the variable is defined) of `theDbSet` is `object`, the compiler knows no more. Use Preston's suggestion if the type `MyClassType` is accessible (in scope). If `MyClassType` is not accessible as a compile-time type, the "cast" operation is not meaningful.

Comment: you _can_ cast to a type known only at runtime. Instead of declaring theDbSet as type object declare it as type dynamic. Check out dynamics here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx